# Rake db:seed can't find .xml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, database, import, rake

Total ruby on rails newbie here.

I'm trying to populate a database within a ruby on rails framework. This is what my seeds.rb file looks like:

```
f = File.open("db/courses.xml")
doc = Nokigiri::XML(f)
f.close

doc.css("course").each do |node|
    children = node.children

Course.create(:name => children.css("name"),
    :description => children.css("description"))
end
```

I haven't been able to test this code, because the rake db:seed command keeps saying "No such file or directoy --- courses.xml". Note that I've both tried "courses.xml" and "db/courses.xml" as paths.

The file courses.xml is in the same folder as the seeds.rb file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the path from the root of the application.  Like this:

```
f = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'courses.xml'))
```